# What are some methods to measure luminance of image using opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, luminance

I need to measure luminance of image with opencv c++ in different ways.

One way is converting image to YUV ,then calculating luminance. Is there any other way you suggest?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of YUV, just convert the image to standard grayscale.